# Searching keywords inside the nested arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an object and its array that contain multiple arrays like below

```
Obj A1:  {
       a: [
        [gta, lol, dota],
        [11, 33, 44],
        [a, b, c, d]
       ]
    }

Obj A2:  {
       a: [
        [Starcraft],
        [11, 33, 44],
        [a, b, c, d]
       ]
    }
```

I need to return documents that have `dota` inside the array `a`. How can I do that with `.find()`? I used `.find({ a: /dota/i})`. However, it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its 2 level nested array, you can use nested `$elemMatch` and `$eq`,

```
db.collection.find({
  a: {
    $elemMatch: {
      $elemMatch: {
        $eq: "dota"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WovKkdFW02l)